# Saving UIScrollView position AND zoom

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` that displays a large map. I have been able to determine how to save the content offset of the current map position, however, it only works when the map is zoomed all of the way in. This makes sense to me since the content offset will be completely different based on what the zoomLevel is.

I had hoped that the solution was as simple as setting the zoomLevel then the `contentOffset` on load, however I can't make this work. The app is correctly saving the contentOffset and zoomLevel to `NSUSerDefaults`, but I just can't get the `scrollView` to zoom to those values when the app loads.

Has anyone had success doing this correctly?

Comment: Do you just want to zoom the map?

Comment: I need to be able to zoom in to the portion the user was looking at...so zoom and scroll.